# Need (Teradata) SQL Help On Selecting Specific Rows

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a query that pulls the following table, but what I'm really interested in grabbing are the highlighted rows that my results are generating.  I was trying to write a case statement within the query, but I realized that I'm omitting some of the grp_mkt records I'm trying to keep.  Logic is essentially is i want records of segments not in grp_mkt AND segments if you are not in grp_mkt. I can probably do a join of the same query to find this but the tables are massive (impression level data) that I'd rather not try to pull the tables again.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to pull segments once, with the prioritization to any market but `grp_market`.  Here is one way:

```
with t as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by segment order by (case when market = grp_mkt then 1 else 2 end) desc) as seqnum
      from <your query/table here>  t
     )
select t.*
from t
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you could have multiple segments (non-grpmkt) and you want all of them, then using `rank()` instead of `row_number()` would work.

Comment: thanks, i tweaked this slightly but this logic worked!